# SUM() of COUNT() in SQL query

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

I have following tables:

**Persons**:

```
PersonID(PK)
AppartmentID(FK)
Name
```

**Appartments**:

```
AppartmentID(PK)
BuildingID(FK)
ApartmentNumber
```

**Buildings**:

```
BuildingID
Address
```

I am trying to get how many people live in each building, something like that:

```
| Address  | Sum |
|----------|-----|
| Address1 | 169 |
| Address2 | 353 |
| Address3 | 232 |
| Address4 | 199 |
```

The best query I got so far is:

```
SELECT 
   Buildings.BuildingID,
   sum(c)
FROM
   (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as c 
    FROM 
        Persons
    GROUP BY 
        Persons.AppartmentID) as c, Appartments
GROUP BY 
    Buildings.BuildingID;
```

But it is not working as I expect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.BuildingID, 
       b.Address, 
       count(p.personID) as persons
FROM Buildings b
LEFT JOIN Appartments a ON a.BuildingID = b.BuildingID
INNER JOIN Persons p ON p.AppartmentID = a.AppartmentID
GROUP BY b.BuildingID, b.Address
```

Comment: Great! But what if I want to display an Address even if there are no Child records associated with it ?

Comment: Got it! I need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN.